# Docker Machine network error on public network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-machine

I have an issue where I'm unable to start any docker machines whilst connected to a the WiFi network in my local Starbucks, receiving the following output;

> $ docker-machine start
>   Starting "default"...
>   (default) Check network to re-create if needed...
>   **Error setting up host only network on machine start: host-only cidr conflicts with the network address of a host interface**

This does not happen when connected to my home network, or whilst using my mobile hotspot. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Did the existing answer help you or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a collision between the docker machine and the network that is being set up for wifi. Try creating a new docker machine with other ip:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.123.99/24" mymachine
```

Use it:

```
docker-machine env mymachine
```

This is a new machine in addition to the 'default' one. You might see that it won't have your previous work (images, etc).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had the chance to return to the Starbucks causing the issue so I cannot test, but this certainly seems like the solution so I'll go with this and hopefully comment with confirmation once tested.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

Your docker-machine start failed.
So either you create new VM or repair existing VM.

1. For new VM option, use --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "10.10.10.1/24"
   (replace 10.10.10.1/24 with whatever subnet you want VM to use.)
2. For already created VM(start failed), bring up the virtual box UI and change it in the network preferences.
   Use docker-machine ls to list existing VMs.